# Is normalizing each pixel value in a UIImage necessary before passing it to a CoreML model?

Tags: swift, image-processing, uiimage, pytorch, coreml

We have a converted a pytorch model into CoreML using https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/ONNXLive.html. We have resized our image to the necessary specifications before inputting that image into the CoreML model. Despite doing this, the output of the CoreML model yields different (and incorrect) results from the pytorch model.

Our machine learning model is used to identify a particular object in an image.
Before sending an image into our model, we slice it into an array of UIImage. Using a for loop, we resize each image in the array before sending each of them to the model. The model accepts a UIImage as an input and returns an integer 0 (object not detected) or 1 (object detected) the result. If the return result is 1, we highlight that particular image in the array. After the for loop ends, we merge the array elements toto form a new UIImage with part of its area highlighted (indicating which positions contain the object).

The model works fine in pytorch, but after we converted it into CoreML and use it with Swift, we encountered a problem such that the model identifies most of the images from the array with the output "1" (for example, if we slice an image into 400 smaller pieces and pass each piece into the model, 356 out of 400 results is "1".)

We suspect the reason for this failure is that we didn't normalize each pixel value of the input image before we sent it to the model. 
Is it necessary to normalize a UIImage when using CoreML, and if so, how should we go about this?

Comment: Does the PyTorch code normalize the input pixels before running the model? Is there an image preprocessing layer in the Core ML model?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: For your first question, the PyTorch code does not normalize the input pixels before running. For the second one, there is no image preprocessing layer in the Core ML model. We are testing with a new model now (still in Core ML model), will see how it goes.